# How to choose subnetwork where DHCP is for VPN clients in Windows 2008?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, vpn, dhcp, rras

I have Windows Server 2008 (non-R2) with RRAS and VPN roles enabled.

How to specify an interface or a subnetwork available for server where DHCP server for VPN clients is located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RAS -> Server properties -> IPv4 -> Adapter

[image]